# How to sort the two line character in R

Tags: r, sorting

How can I sort the variable (pair) which is two line label in the following order:

```
Pair<-c("CA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.00)", "CA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.00)",
 "EA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.41)", "EA.F - CA.F\n(P-value=0.00)",
 "EA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.32)", "EA.M - CA.M\n(P-value=0.33)",
 "SA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.08)", "SA.F - CA.F\n(P-value=0.00)",
 "SA.F - EA.F\n(P-value=0.99)", "SA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.95)",
 "SA.M - CA.M\n(P-value=0.01)", "SA.M - EA.M\n(P-value=0.94)")

lwr<-c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,14,16)
upr<-c(5,6,7,8,10,12,14,14,13,14,15,15)
Final<-data.frame(Pair,lwr,upr)
```

**I want to sort variable (pair) in this format and add it into the data set as a new variable:**

```
c("SA.M - EA.M","SA.M - CA.M","EA.M - CA.M","SA.M - BK.M", 
"EA.M - BK.M","CA.M - BK.M","SA.F - EA.F","SA.F - CA.F",
"EA.F - CA.F","SA.F - BK.F","EA.F - BK.F","CA.F - BK.F")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you want to reorder `Pair` according to the labels in the second vector. If so, then you could do the following:

**Data:**

```
Pair<-c("CA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.00)", "CA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.00)",
"EA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.41)", "EA.F - CA.F\n(P-value=0.00)",
"EA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.32)", "EA.M - CA.M\n(P-value=0.33)",
"SA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.08)", "SA.F - CA.F\n(P-value=0.00)",
"SA.F - EA.F\n(P-value=0.99)", "SA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.95)",
"SA.M - CA.M\n(P-value=0.01)", "SA.M - EA.M\n(P-value=0.94)")

customOrder = c("SA.M - EA.M","SA.M - CA.M","EA.M - CA.M","SA.M - BK.M",
"EA.M - BK.M","CA.M - BK.M","SA.F - EA.F","SA.F - CA.F",
"EA.F - CA.F","SA.F - BK.F","EA.F - BK.F","CA.F - BK.F")
```

The vector `customOrder` is how you want to order `Pair`

**Do:**

```
ordered = sapply(customOrder, function(x){grep(x,Pair)})
```

**Result:**

```
lwr<-c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,14,16)
upr<-c(5,6,7,8,10,12,14,14,13,14,15,15)
Final<-data.frame(Pair,lwr,upr)

Final[ordered,]

                          Pair lwr upr
12 SA.M - EA.M\n(P-value=0.94)  16  15
11 SA.M - CA.M\n(P-value=0.01)  14  15
6  EA.M - CA.M\n(P-value=0.33)   7  12
10 SA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.95)  13  14
5  EA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.32)   6  10
2  CA.M - BK.M\n(P-value=0.00)   3   6
9  SA.F - EA.F\n(P-value=0.99)  11  13
8  SA.F - CA.F\n(P-value=0.00)   9  14
4  EA.F - CA.F\n(P-value=0.00)   5   8
7  SA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.08)   8  14
3  EA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.41)   4   7
1  CA.F - BK.F\n(P-value=0.00)   2   5
```

Comment: instead of `sapply(customOrder, function(x){grep(x,Pair)})` you can just reduce this to `sapply(customOrder,grep,Pair)`

Comment: @R. Schifini, thanks so much for the solution. The problem is that as soon as I will bring the information into the ggplot, I cannot keep this order. Is there any way to reorder pair variable and save it as a new variable to make sure to have the same order in ggplot?

Comment: @user8322300 Ask another question about the plot order with ggplot. Include your code attempt and the data. If you found this answer useful, please accept it by checking it.